Copy where clause on both joined tabled, equivalence
I wonder if these two queries are equivalent :
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.id=42

And:
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.id=42 AND t2.id=42

Thought, it is a very reduced case of an expensive query, with a big IN (many values) instead of =42. In my case, the second version is faster by a magnitude. I feel the optimization is too simple and I am missing something. But what ?

"Reducing" the case ended up in obfuscation, as IN is handled differently from =. To be clear, logical equivalence does not necessarily translate to the same query plan. When you ask for "equivalence", you'll need to be more specific, I guess. Start a new question showing your actual query along with relevant table definitions and necessary information for postgresql-performance if you want to dig deeper.

The answer is yes, the queries are the same due to the use of equivalence classes.
It works only for equality (=42) but not (yet) for more complicated cases (inequality, IN...).
Reference: Postgres Planner Quirks: JOIN Equivalence Classes and IN/ANY filters By Lukas Fittl.

The planner uses equivalence classes to deduce implied conditions. That is, we have the join condition a.adate = b.bdate and then you've added the where condition a.adate = '2021-05-12'. Transitivity implies that b.bdate = '2021-05-12', so we deduce that condition and are able to apply it at the relation scan of b.
Furthermore, having restricted both a.adate and b.bdate to the same constant value at the scan level, we no longer need to apply the join condition a.adate = b.bdate at all. This is important not only to avoid the (probably minor) inefficiency of rechecking the join condition, but because if we believed that all three conditions were independently applicable, we'd come out with a serious underestimate of the size of the join result. - Tom Lane

